# Python: How can I create a data file from a converted csv file?

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to convert a csv file into another file (file type doesn't matter as the program using the converted data just opens it like a text file).

So far I have managed to convert and print the original csv data into the the data structure I want but I now need to save that as another file.

```
import csv
file = open('newData', 'w')

with open('initialData.csv', 'rb') as f:
reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
for row in reader:
    print row[13] + ' 1:' + row[0] + ' 2:' + row[1]
    file.write(f)

file.close()
```

Whenever I run this I get the error:

```
TypeError: expected a character buffer object
```

I know there is nothing wrong with converting the csv file as that prints fine when I comment out the file.write(f).

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Please *do* include the full traceback when reporting a python error, so we won't have to guess as much.

Comment: Your indentation is incorrect.  Please ensure that the indentation you see in your question matches your original source code *exactly*.

Comment: Fix your indentation. For SO code samples, it's best to set your editor to indent with spaces, not tabs.

Comment: Also, while you're at it, you should use `with..as` for the output file as well. Also, don't name them `file` (that's a built-in) and `f`. Use something like `infile` and `outfile`.

Comment: You're using csv.reader for the input. Why not use csv.writer for the output?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why are you trying to write the original file (the `f` object) to the new file? Don't you want to write the re-formatted data?

```
import csv

with open('initialData.csv', 'rb') as f_in, open('newData', 'w') as f_out:
    reader = csv.reader(f_in, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
    for row in reader:
        print row[13] + ' 1:' + row[0] + ' 2:' + row[1]
        f_out.write(row[13] + ' 1:' + row[0] + ' 2:' + row[1])
```

**Edit:** as suggested by Jon Clements, use context manager for output as well + indentation fix.

Comment: Gosh I can't believe I didn't see that before! Thanks for your help!

Comment: @mrpopo - don't sweat it, I've made that sort of mistake more times than I care to admit. So easy to overlook.

Comment: Couple of changes: `with open('in.csv') as f, open('out.csv','wb') as fo` (make the most of your `with`), then don't indent the `for`

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to print out the file handle for the whole csv file. I'm guessing you want the text you're printing to be written out into a file, in that case just do:

```
with open('initialData.csv', 'rb') as infile, open('newData.txt') as outfile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile, ...)
    for row in reader:
        outfile.write(row[13] + ' 1:' + row[0] + ' 2:' + row[1])
```